# How does QGIS read in projection information from hdf5 files? Projection info not recognized

Tags: hdf5, gdal, qgis, map-projections

When i bring an HDF5 file into QGIS that contains raster information, the data visually appear however spatially, they are not projected properly. QGIS does not read the spatial CRS information embedded in the hdf5 file.

Does anyone know what QGIS looks for in terms of syntax and attributes (and where) when it opens an HDF5 file? I'd like to adjust my HDF5 files so that the CRS information reads and QGIS can project the data.

Thank you for any direction
Leah

Answer (score 0):

According to the [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_hdf5.html) documentation for the HDF5 driver there is no standard way of doing so.

But something worth trying is to peek at a file which does work for you. Unfortunately i don't have a GDAL driver which can write HDF5 files, but i can create a HDF4 file. If i convert a (georeferenced) Geotiff to HDF4 with GDAL, QGIS reads it correctly, with CRS information etc.

GDAL creates four global attributes, it might be worth trying to create those in your HDF5 file. I'm not sure if all of them are necessary, the 'Signature' doesn't seem crucial. Though it really depends on the implementation of HDF5 in QGIS, it could be completely different compared to HDF4.

[image]

Comment: Hello there - thank you very much for the thoughtful response. When you create the HDF4 file, are you doing so in python? i can write a hdf5 file but am not sure how to go about assigning projection information to it. would you be open to sharing your code with me so i can better understand how to convert from geotiff to hdf4? i can then translate this to hdf5. thank you again. this is very useful!